# Choosing balls out of a box

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

We choose balls out of a box. In a box we have 2 white balls with numbers 1 and 2, three black balls with numbers 1,2,3. From a box without replacement we choose two balls. Let X denote biggest number chosen and Y denote number of white balls we have chosen. Find $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$. I know i have to find  $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=1)$,$\mathbb{E}(Y|X=2)$,$\mathbb{E}(Y|X=3)$. Then i need to set up a system of equations, but how to find those single conditional values?

---

**EDIT:** (still i have not received a satisfactory answer.
Now i am looking for a solution for: $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$.
Thus:

1. $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=0)=0*1+\frac{1}{3}*2+\frac{2}{3}*3$
2. $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=1)=\frac{1}{6}*1+\frac{1}{2}*2+\frac{2}{6}*3$
3. $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=2)=2$

Is this attempt correct?

Comment: There are only $10$ equally likely pairs...simply enumerating all the cases is straight forward.  Worth doing, even if you prefer to think it through abstractly....that way you'll have a clear test case to compare to your general formula.

Comment: Still i do not think i know what should i do.

Comment: Ok.  Start with the case $X=1$.  What is the probability that $X=1$?  Given that $X=1$, what can you say about $Y$?

Comment: $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}$? The same thing for $E(Y|X=1)=\frac{5}{6}$?

Comment: Does that sound right to you?  Think about the possible pairs.  Actually just list all the possible pairs.  How many of them have $X=1$?

Comment: Only one? I mean $(1,1)$? That's the expectation?

Comment: Yes, that's the only pair.  So...$P(X=1)=?$  And, what is $E(Y|X=1)$?

Comment: Simply equal to one?

Comment: Exactly.  In fact, knowing that $X=1$ forces $Y=1$, no probability involved in that.  Now do the same calculation for $X=2$.  This time there are more than one pair, and $Y$ is not determined uniquely.

Comment: will it be $E(Y|X=2)=0.5\times 1+2\times 0.25$?

Comment: I see four equally likely pairs with $X=2$, namely $(1W,2W),(1W,2B),(2W,1B),(2W,2B)$, yes?  In three of these, $Y=1$, in one of them $Y=2$.  Thus I get $E(Y|X=2)=1*.75+2*.25$.

Comment: why not (1B,2B)?

Comment: Because I missed it!  Good catch.  So there are five equally likely pairs.  The new one gives $Y=0$ so  $E(Y|X=2)=0*.2+1*.6+2*.2$, unless I have made another blunder (always possible).

Comment: and  $E(Y│X=3)=0*1/2+1/4*1+2*1/4=0.75$?

Comment: For $X=3$, we know we must have chosen $3B$.  The other can be any of the remaining four.  Choosing $1B$ or $2B$ gives $Y=0$, choosing $1W$ or $2W$ gives $Y=1$.  Where do you get a case giving $Y=2$?

Comment: $E(Y│X=3)=0*1/2+1/2*1+2*0$?

Comment: Well, yes...though the $Y=2$ with probability $0$ case needn't be there (there are lots of cases with probability $0$).  Doesn't change the result, of course.  Looks like you've got it!  If you want to, you can post a full solution below.  Good to organize everything and the site frowns on unanswered questions.

Comment: Summing up the answer is: $E(X│Y)=-0.25Y^2+0.75Y+0.5$?

Comment: You mean $E(Y|X)$?  That's what you have been computing.  So the answer ought to be a function of $X$, not $Y$.

Comment: Yes' you are right appreciate your help

Comment: What about the other way round? I mean: $E(X|Y)$

Comment: Well, you have to repeat all the steps.  In principle you can have $Y=0,1,2$ and you have to compute in each case separately.  Same procedure as before.

Comment: I have changed everything is this attempt correct now?

Comment: well, your calculation is correct but I expect you were meant to write it as a random variable in $Y$.

Comment: The question had two parts one was  about $E(X|Y)$ and the other about $E(Y|X)$.